# Get author posts count after excluding a category

Tags: posts, plugin-development, mysql

I want to display the posts count of each author, but posts that are in some categories should be excluded from the count.

I tried doing this with `count_user_posts( $user->ID )`, but this function doesn't have any category excluding options. My second approach was to do this by querying the posts table with mySQL's `COUNT` function, but the category IDs are not stored in that table, so I can´t exclude categories this way.

Now, before I do some weird and less performant `JOIN` querys, I hope someone can show me a better way how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a query using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts://) to retrieve posts from a specific author, and exclude certain categories, and then use [`count`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.count.php) to return the amount of posts. `get_posts` uses the same parameters as [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), so you can have a look at the parameters there

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'author' => 1 //ID of the author
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //Retrieve all posts
    'category' => -13, // Category to exclude, must be ID, as category is passed to WP_Query as cat
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
echo count($posts_array); //Display post count
```

Comment: yes this works but this call has a very bad performance. I´ve some authors with over 20k posts ( automated content from other sites ). Its causing a timeout error there. I think this is because the whole postdate will be loaded with this call.

Comment: sorry i mean postdata not "postdate" ;)

Comment: I did not realize the shear amount of posts per author> you should update your question with that info